# express.js compress middleware do not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gzip

I have the following middlewares in my app:

```
app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/static/public/images/favicon.ico'));
app.use(express.compress());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.cookieParser('SECRET!'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + config.static_path, {maxAge: 365 * 86400000}));
app.use(express.session({secret: 'SECRET!'}));
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(app.router);
```

headers example:
[image: jquery.js headers]

But the static content do not compressing. What could be the problem?

Comment: How are you checking them ? Browser usually decompresses them automatically. Compressed requests would have a `Content-Encoding` header set. Check their headers.

Comment: @user568109 I checking headers and there is no `Content-Encoding` and google plugin for chrome that analyzes page speed advises to enable gzip...

Comment: `compress` must be high enough in middleware chain to compress responses so favicon would be going out uncompressed. Can you adjust that and check again.

Comment: @user568109 i tryed to move compress middleware to the first place in middleware chain, but nothing has changed

Comment: @Kirill what's that `Via` header doing there? Are you proxying requests to Express? If so, are you sure that the `Accept-Encoding` header is actually passed and/or that the proxy isn't otherwise interfering?

Comment: @robertklep thx, the problem was because i used rerouting to 80-th port: `iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are several reasons why your static content may not get compressed:

- `express.compress` maintains a minimum file size threshold; files with a size below this threshold (default: 1024 bytes) won't get compressed;
- `express.compress` also maintains a whitelist of content types to compress; if you're serving files with a content type that's not on that list, it won't get compressed either;

To fix:

```
app.use(express.compress({
  threshold : 0, // or whatever you want the lower threshold to be
  filter    : function(req, res) {
    var ct = res.get('content-type');
    // return `true` for content types that you want to compress,
    // `false` otherwise
    ...
  }
}));
```

(as a reference, [this](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/compress.html#exports.filter) is the default filter function used)

Comment: i check headers of jquery.js file (size over 90kb and content type is application/javascript which passes through the filter)

Comment: @Kirill You said jquery.js. If it is not minified the size is about 250Kb for recent versions. 90kb would mean it is gzipped. See http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/jquery-size

Comment: @user568109 90K is about the size of a minified (but not necessarily compressed) jQuery.

Comment: @user568109 robertklep is right jquery is really minified... Sorry for not a full explanation :)

Comment: this is very useful!

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in rerouting to 80-th port like :

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

Thanks to @robertklep for help!

Comment: How did you solve the issue ? Even I am trying to reroute to a different port.